Heroku Prisma Error occurred during query execution after commit
I'm developing an app using NestJs + Ionic stack.
I'm using Heroku to deploy my Nest app and Supabase for Postgres database.
Everything was working just fine for past several days, but today I faced problem I just can't solve.
After commiting some changes to github, Heroku automatically deploys new version of an app. It worked perfectly but today after commit which included just some console.log clearance I can't use my backend. When I'm trying to send a request Heroku logs look just like this:
[31m[Nest] 46  - [39m07/26/2024, 5:27:19 PM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[ExceptionsHandler] [39m[31m
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347590+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347590+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347591+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347591+00:00 app[web.1]: Error occurred during query execution:
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347592+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(PostgresError { code: "42P05", message: "prepared statement \"s0\" already exists", severity: "ERROR", detail: None, column: None, hint: None }), transient: false })[39m
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347615+00:00 app[web.1]: PrismaClientUnknownRequestError: 
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347616+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347616+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-07-26T17:27:19.347616+00:00 app[web.1]:

It is weird because I didn't make any changes to Prisma Schema, everything is the same, just random commit. Deleting Supabase project and creating new one solved the problem. Everything was working but when I commited again (I wanted to check if this gonna happen again) I got the same problem.
Like I said, both commits included just some whitespaces and console.log cleaning so I don't know what is the issue and why deleting whole database helped.
PS deleting all the tables from db doesn't solve the problem. I had to delete whole Supabase project and create a new one
